# Unable to move mouse cursor while pressing keyboard button

Tags: unity, input

I've a player to which I've attached character controller and two scripts - `Controller` and `MouseLooker` to control the player movements but when I try to move my mouse cursor while pressing keyboard key(s), my mouse cursor gets locked. When I release the keyboard keys(s) it starts working.

How should I fix this to get both keyboard and mouse to work at the same time?

Comment: I could not see your code, for some reason it is not opening in my browser, but for the mouse purpose, you can treat it separately, may be [this link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116555/aiming-direction-using-mouse/116561#116561) will help you

Comment: Paste has, at this point, expired.

Comment: That's why it's better to paste the code into the question and not rely on external links that can go down.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is related to something in the UPDATE() method on your MouseLooker script.

The LockCursor() calls need some tweaking.

Is this happening with only 1 keyboard key, or several keyboard keys?

Also, you may get more insight into what is happening if you added some "print()" calls in your "UPDATE()" methods, which output the cursor lock state, and some other code based values to help you troubleshoot.