# Aiming direction using mouse

Tags: unity, rotation, aiming

I'm using the following code to rotate my object using mouse, for aiming direction. The only problem with this is that it only rotates between 0 to 180 and not full 360 degrees. Can any help me locate the problem?

```
void Update()
{
  var pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.gameObject.transform.position);
  var dir = (Input.mousePosition - pos).normalized;
  var angle = (Mathf.Atan2(dir.z, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 270) % 360;
  this.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.down);

  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
  {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(dir.x * Force, 0, dir.y * Force, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: So you want that your object will face your mouse pointer?

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15070/orienting-a-model-to-face-a-target (and you can probably figure this out on your own from reviewing this)

Comment: I'm asking because your rotation seems strongly related to your object position

Comment: @HamzaHasan: This is actually the striker of carrom game. I want user to be able to chose a direction (0 to 360 for now) by moving the mouse.

Comment: In which way? by just facing mouse pointer or there is something else for this in your plan?

Comment: @HamzaHasan: Currently just facing mouse pointer, but it should be in all directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your answer is good for your specific situation but you could use [LookAtMouse](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=LookAtMouse) script. That is very handy, beautiful and will work in all type of circumstances.

Pasting the important part of script that you can use easily.

```
public float speed = 10;

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Generate a plane that intersects the transform's position with an upwards normal.
        Plane playerPlane = new Plane (Vector3.up, transform.position);

        // Generate a ray from the cursor position
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        // Determine the point where the cursor ray intersects the plane.
        // This will be the point that the object must look towards to be looking at the mouse.
        // Raycasting to a Plane object only gives us a distance, so we'll have to take the distance,
        //   then find the point along that ray that meets that distance.  This will be the point
        //   to look at.
        float hitdist = 0.0f;
        // If the ray is parallel to the plane, Raycast will return false.
        if (playerPlane.Raycast (ray, out hitdist)) {
            // Get the point along the ray that hits the calculated distance.
            Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint (hitdist);

            // Determine the target rotation.  This is the rotation if the transform looks at the target point.
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (targetPoint - transform.position);

            // Smoothly rotate towards the target point.
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Hamza. This one is certainly better than mine and more general-purpose too.

Answer (score 0):

Got it myself. The above code should look like this:

```
var pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.gameObject.transform.position);
var dir = (Input.mousePosition - pos);
var angle = (Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg) - 90;
this.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.down);
```